# More readable way to write code with strings which contain quotes `"`

Tags: string, scala

I found some scala code hard to read:

```
val names = List("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
var result = names.mkString(""" ["""", """","""", """"] """)
println(result)
```

You can see the code contains `"` looks ugly. I'm looking for better solutions for the same code.

We may use `\"` to make it shorter:

```
names.mkString(" [\"", "\",\"", "\"] ")
```

But it still not readable.

If scala supports string wrapped in `'`, then we will have a best solution:

```
names.mkString(' ["', '","', '"] ');
```

I'm looking for some other solutions to make the code more readable.

Comment: Probably using Symbols? It has a name method.

Comment: Not that much more readable and comes at a cost, but I guess there is `names.mkString("['","','","']").replaceAll("'","\"")`...

Comment: As in this case you have spaces in your text, the Symbols are not applicable, but the xml literals are. Probably a an implicit conversion might help to remove boilerplate (while keeping import scope limited). Probably I would go with the one of your options though, I find the second one easier to read/write.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that if your input list could contain strings that include `"`, you'll need to quote them properly. If that's the case, you might as well do all the quoting in a separate `map` stage.

Answer (score 2):

Multiline quoting proves convenient, yet not fully readable in some occasions. Consider this minor syntactic rearrangement,

```
val LSEP = """ [""""
val SEP  = """",""""
val RSEP = """"] """

val names = List("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
var result = names.mkString(LSEP, SEP, RSEP)
println(result)
```